# newbie time difference

Tags: time-series

good day!

i need help and be guided on the right path here, i'm pretty sure i'm lost. im trying to compute for time diffrence for start time and end time manually versus automatic ex. online computation.

start time =08:55 am
end time =13:22 pm

for manual computation, i did this.

8-13 =4 hrs
55-22 =33 min

I know that getting the time difference is by subtracting both start time(hour) -end time(hour) and 
both start time(minutes) -end time(minutes) 
combine both =4:33 hrs in total manually

I did not *60 or divide 60 because its not over 60.

my problem is when I try computing this online 
ex:http://www.onlineconversion.com/days_between_advanced.htm
http://www.grun1.com/utils/timeDiff.cfm

the total time is:
4:27:00 hrs

is there another computation that needs to be done. if so can you help me. am i wrong

thank you

Comment: $8-13=4$?? Not $8-13=-5$? I think this is where your confusion starts.

Comment: thank you for your response, sorry for the wrong entry for 8-13 =4, i did not notice it until you pointed it out.

Answer (score 1):

Count hours and minutes separately, and then use the fact that $1$:$00=0$:$60$.

$13$:$22-08$:$55=(13-8)$:$(22-55)=5$:$(-33)=4$:$27$

Comment: thank you for your immediate response, cant wait to try this on other computation i'll do next.